# What is the priority order of the four groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: Molecule]

I'm trying to figure out whether this is in R/S configuration....I thought it would be R since the groups seem to be decreasing in priority in the clockwise direction (since F has the largest atomic number). However, the answers say that it is actually in the S configuration....could someone explain this to me? Have I incorrectly assigned priority?

Comment: So what if F has the largest atomic number? It is not like we look at the whole group and count the largest atomic numbers. No, we look at the **first** atom alone, and think of it for a while. If that's indecisive, we look further...

Comment: Oh ok....so does that mean that the MeO group has highest priority followed by CF3...?

Comment: Looks like so.$\,$

Comment: The priority is MeO > CF3 > COOH. I think the configuration is R.